# Asus Prime a320m-k Motherboard Yellow light flashing

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I have build a pc with an Asus Prime a320m-k Motherboard and AMD Athlon 200GE CPU.

According to the Asus website the CPU is only compatible from BIOS version 4400. When i turn the pc on the fans goes on and a yellow light at the PCI slot flashes (1 - 2 sec interval) and also on the motherboard near the Audio outputs at the back. There is no screen output when i connect to my monitor.

I have one Kingston 4GB DDR4 ram 2400 mhz.  I still need to check what BIOS version it is but was hoping i could turn on the pc and go to the BIOS setup, but i can't (blue screen) I also don't seem to find the Light indicators reasons for this motherboard.

Attached is a image of the motherboard and where the lights are on

[Motherboard image with yellow light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNHt1.jpg)

Edited...

Ok, so i connected the PC to my monitor again but this time i ensured my monitor is on before turning on the PC. When i turned on the PC it worked. But with the light still on. I was able to install windows and everything works as expected, but why is the light still on? I check the BIOS version and it should be compatible with the CPU according to Asus BIOS updates.

Comment: Well, sounds like the current BIOS doesn't support this CPU.

Comment: And it does not seem to have BIOS flashback. So i need to get another CPU